Definition of angle measure from Pedoe's Geometry
I'm going through Pedoe's book for the first time. I'm fairly ok with elementary real analysis and modern algebra, but I want to relearn Euclidean geometry since I was never trained comprehensively in it when I was younger.
Am I understanding correctly that Pedoe is saying there is a canonical bijection for any circle $C$ of radius $r$ centered at $(h,k)$ of the form
$$
    \begin{gather*}
        [0,\pi) \to C \\
        t \mapsto (r\cos t + h,r\sin t + k)
    \end{gather*}
$$
such that the rays that define the angle can be uniquely identified with real numbers $t \in [0,2\pi)$ by where the ray's intersection with the point $(r\cos t + h,r\sin t + k)$ occurs. And, from this the angle measures are just differences of real numbers $\mathrm{mod}\; 2\pi$?  Here's the page in Google books for reference: Pedoe's Geometry on Google Books

Given any point on the unit circle, since the region bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$ and thus every subset of it is measurable, every sector formed by the line segmet joining the point to the origin and the positive $x$-axis can be assigned an area. You can then associate a real number with each point on the circle by defining it as twice the area of the corresponding sector. More precisely,

$$\theta:\{(x,y)|x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}\longrightarrow [0,2\pi)$$ defined
by$$\theta(x,y)=2\times\cases{\displaystyle\qquad\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+\int_{1}^{x}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}dt\quad
> \text{if }x\in[-1,1],\ y\in[0,1], x^{2}+y^{2}=1 \\\displaystyle
\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+\int_{-1}^{x}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}dt\quad
> \text{if }x\in[-1,1),\ y\in[-1,0], x^{2}+y^{2}=1}$$

You can then use derivatives to show that this mapping is indeed bijective.
